# Button Coming From Bottom After Pressing

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an extremely simple iOS app. I press a button and the image changes. The problem I'm running into is every time I press the button, it's like the button goes to the bottom of the phone simulator and lays on top of the button I originally pressed.

Also the image only stays for a split second before disappearing. (I'm assuming these actions go hand in hand).

Here is the code if anyone is able to help.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func generateHero(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //list of Images in array
        let image : NSArray = [ UIImage(named: "batman.jpg")!,
                                UIImage(named: "the-flash.jpg")!,
                                UIImage(named: "Deadpool.jpg")!,
                                UIImage(named: "green-arrow.jpg")!,
                                UIImage(named: "iron-man.jpg")!]

        //random image generating method
        let imagerange: UInt32 = UInt32(image.count)
        let randomimage = Int(arc4random_uniform(imagerange))
        let generatedimage: AnyObject = image.object(at: randomimage) as AnyObject
        self.heroImage.image = generatedimage as? UIImage
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var heroImage: UIImageView!
}
```

Comment: post how you create the button and it's action , also why **NSArray** in swift

Comment: Have you used Auto Layout for setting positions of the button and image view?

Comment: @Sh_Khan All I did with the button was create it in the storyboard, then add some constraints. I'm assuming that's the problem, I need to create the actual button in ViewController.swift?

Comment: @AlexSmet I'm honestly not sure... I did, and undid a lot. I'm very new to swift, and just trying to piece things together. My apologies.

Comment: Show us your constraint of the heroImage

Comment: @TungVuDuc The only restraints I have are horizontally and vertically in center. I ended up taking everything else off because nothing was working anyway. It's basically been one horrible game of guess and check.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a lot of unnecessary conversions in random image generation, if you have used **Array** instead of **NSArray** you could use .randomElement() function that returns random element of array. So you would just do 
`self.heroImage.image = image.randomElement()`